# How to fix "ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy, Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden" when making a request in Python using requests library?

Tags: python, https, python-requests, proxy, request

I am working on my pet project and have chosen [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) for hosting

to implement some functionality, I need to take information from sites
but when I execute the following code

```
import requests


response = requests.get(
        "https://example.com", 
        proxies={"http":"http://162.120.71.11:80"}, 
        headers={"User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; de) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00"}
        )

print( response.text )
```

I'm getting an error

```
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', O
SError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

I tried changing user agents and proxies but nothing changed

and also I tried to make a request to different sites and for some sites it worked but not for those that I need

Comment: Server is is saying "nope, you cant do that" ..  How about you ask the proxy host what you need to do to access it ?

Comment: @rasjani 
everything is much simpler 
"allowed list"
you can access only the sites on the list

Comment: The proxy you use can be blacklisted by the site. Just remove the proxy and retry.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and it appears that the domain needs to be in the whitelist if you're using the free plan:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/27261/